# Add Random Number in PHP Code to Create and Show Random Image

Tags: php, caching, random, captcha

I have this php code like:

```
imagejpeg($img, "mydir/captcha.jpg", 100);
```

I want to add a random number infront of captcha so captcha.jpg becomes like captcha3432.jpg and next time captcha9787.jpg.

with

```
$number2= rand(555511, 99879);
```

How do I add **$number2** infront of **captcha** like > **captcha$number2.jpg**

Please advise.

Comment: your question is about first lesson in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imagejpeg($img, "mydir/captcha".$number2.".jpg", 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

`imagejpeg($img, "mydir/captcha{$number2}.jpg", 100);`

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much answered your own question. When using double quotes you can parse variables in a string, like so. Note that this behavior doesn't work with single quotes.

```
$number2 = rand(555511, 99879);
imagejpeg($img, "mydir/captcha$number2.jpg", 100);
```